# Ruby return wrong type

Tags: ruby

```
def starts_with_consonant?(str)
    str.empty? || str.class != String ||  /\A[^aeiou]/i=~str
end
p starts_with_consonant? "Apple" #=>nil
p starts_with_consonant? "microsoft"#=> 0
```

I expect it to return true or false, but it returns nil and 0.

Comment: The expression `/\A[^aeiou]/i=~str` returns the index of the match, which is `0`. Thus your second result.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `str.class != String`? `str.respond_to? :to_str`, `str.is_a? String`, and `str.respond_to? :to_s; str = str.to_s` might be more appropriate/Rubyish approaches (depending on circumstances of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the Regex test in your last expression returns nil or 0, in the case of a match. You need to coerce the match into a boolean

```
def starts_with_consonant?(str)
   str.empty? || str.class != String ||  (/\A[^aeiou]/i=~str != nil)
end
```

Comment: A common Ruby idiom for that would be `!!(str.empty? || str.class != String ||  /\A[^aeiou]/i=~str)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby every object is considered true(truthy), except for `nil` and `false`. This includes 0:

```
puts '0 is true' if 0
0 is true
```

For all intents and purposes, your code already returns false and true, it will work correctly with `if` or boolean operators like `&&` and `||`.
Only direct comparison will show the difference:

```
starts_with_consonant? "Apple" == false
=> false
```

But such comparison is not needed for anything in Ruby, and often is considered bad style. Just use `if` or `unless`

```
if starts_with_consonant? "Apple"
  #...
end

unless starts_with_consonant? "Apple"
  #...
end
```